# Как правильно написать тесты?

Tags: android, юнит-тесты, mockito

Есть кнопка, по клику я стучусь на сервер в ответ получаю json в зависимости от содержания выполняю соответствующие действия. Как это дело покрыть тестом? Как по клику обрабатывать не реальный метод, а мок.

Comment: подать на вход метода "в зависимости от содержания выполняю соответствующие действия", разные варианты json, покрывающие все ветки в вашем методе, это ели мы говорим о тестировании вашей логики а не кнопок